# App Sandboxing in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sandbox

Is sand-boxing from Xcode or IOS? On the internet I read all the application in

> var/mobile/bundle/application

runs in the sand-box.

But when i build an app in Xcode, is the app sand-boxed.

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sand-boxing is from Xcode or IOS

iOS does the sandboxing -- apps are prevented by the operating system from accessing the file system outside their sandbox, they can't really communicate with each other, etc.

> but when i build an app in Xcode 5

You should update to Xcode 7.2, which is several years newer than Xcode 5.

Any sandbox-related features you may be seeing in Xcode are probably meant for use with OS X applications, which are not necessarily sandboxed.

Answer (score 1):

Apps that are sandboxed are restricted from accessing system APIs that are "unsafe". For instance, iOS apps cannot write files into into other apps' bundles. This is also true for Mac apps distributed through the Mac App Store. For more, [see this link](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/).

As far as Xcode is concerned, it will expose configuration options for sandboxing an app you're building. However, sandboxing is not directly applicable to Xcode itself.